# Can we do a linear transformation on $X$ so that $X$ is the standard Gumbel distribution with $\mu=0$ and $\sigma=1$?

Tags: probability, statistics

Given a random variable $X$ following from Gumbel distribution with location $\mu$ and $\sigma$.

Its density is given by (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gumbel_distribution):
$$
f(x)=\frac{1}{\sigma}\exp(-(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}))\exp(-\exp(-(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})))
$$

Can we do a linear transformation on $X$ so that $X$ is the standard Gumbel distribution with $\mu=0$ and $\sigma=1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [change of variables formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Scalar_to_scalar), if $Y = g(X)$, where $g:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a monotonic function, then
$$f_Y(y) = f_X\big(g^{-1}(y)\big) \left| \frac{d}{dy} \big(g^{-1}(y)\big) \right|.$$
For your case, we use $$g(x) = \frac{x - \mu}{\sigma}.$$
So
$$g^{-1}(y) = \sigma y + \mu, \textrm{ and } \frac{d}{dy} \big(g^{-1}(y)\big) = \sigma$$
Putting this into the formula for $f_Y(y)$ gives
$$f_Y(y) = f_X\big(\sigma y + \mu\big) \left| \sigma \right|,$$
so
$$f_Y(y) = \exp(-(y))\exp(-\exp(-(y))),$$
which is the density of the standard Gumbel distribution.

If by 'linear transformation' you mean $g(x) = \alpha x$ for some $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ then it's not possible: $\alpha = 1/\sigma$ would be necessary to make the normalising constant equal to $1$, but then the density of $\alpha X$ would still include the $\mu$ term.

Comment: So you mean for $X\sim Gumbel(\mu, \sigma)$, then $(X-\mu)/\sigma\sim Gumbel(0, 1)$?

Comment: @Hermi Yes that's right